# c++ modules and using std::list

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-modules

I have a strange issue when I'm trying to use `std::list` with modules.

Here is my simple code:

**module_b.cpp:**

```
module;

import <list>;
import <iostream>;

export module module_b;

export void test_b()
{
    std::cout << "Hello!\n";
    std::list<int> b; // <- this cause the issue
}
```

**main.cpp:**

```
import module_b;

int main()
{
    test_b();
}
```

And here is how I try to build it with g++ 11.2.0 on cygwin:

```
$ g++.exe -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts -c -x c++-system-header list
$ g++.exe -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts -c -x c++-system-header iostream
$ g++ -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts module_b.cpp main.cpp
In module imported at main.cpp:1:1:
module_b: error: failed to read compiled module: Bad file data
module_b: note: compiled module file is ‘gcm.cache/module_b.gcm’
module_b: fatal error: returning to the gate for a mechanical issue
compilation terminated.
```

And it works when I comment-out `std::list<int> b;` in module_b:

```
$ g++ -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts module_b.cpp main.cpp
$ ./a.exe
Hello!
```

So what is the reason? How can I use `list` when using modules?

Comment: That would be a compiler bug. You could try `#include <list>` instead of importing it.

Comment: Unfortunately this also fails during the compilation.

Comment: Is it Visual Studio 2019?

Comment: I'm using gcc version 11.2.0 from cygwin.

Comment: I can confirm this is a bug. Tried the same setup, the same commands. Removing the global module fragment, replacing `<list>` with `<vector>` same issue. I'm using g++ 11.1.0, no this is definitely not the first compiler error with modules I have encountered. There is no reason your example should not work, since you can build module_b by itself just fine: `g++-11 -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts -c module_b.cpp`.

Comment: Thanks for checking this.

Comment: @Adam Not a problem, as I'm actively researching modules atm. If you have any interest, I'm working on a [tool](https://github.com/alexpanter/cpp_module_parser) to determine module interdependencies and generate compile commands.